# php script that detect from user agent what is the device (mobile)?

Tags: php, device, user-agent

I am try to write a php script that return the device from the user agent in the header.

the problem that i see that is not simple to do a regular expression, because the different between the device (am i wrong?)

so i want an updated  list of mobile device according to the user agent

I found this list  : [List of user agents for mobile phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones)

I try to find an updated xml / feed that i can take all the kinds

or other way you think that best to do this .

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after alot of search i think the simple way is to use 
a web service

**This means no downloads, no installs, no hassles... just simple!**

http://www.wurflws.com/

**EDIT:**

The web service is not available now,
i recommend to use  http://deviceatlas.com/ or http://51degrees.mobi/ (commercial) or if you look on open source look on : 
[Best Open Source WURFL alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673535/best-open-source-wurfl-alternative)

Comment: That link seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script in a project of mine

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Works perfect.

All you need to do in your code is include mobile_device_detect.php and then the function `mobile_device_detect()` will return to you the device (Android, IPhone, ...) you're running on

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect2/