# Integrate wurlf in web services java

Tags: java, analytics, wurfl

I search a framework for detecting device. I have my web services in Jersey (java) and i discover [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/wurfl_schema.php)

is possible to integrate this framework with my web services? or exists another framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course it is. It has an implemented Java API, just use that:

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava_index.php

WURFL is really just a big XML file with properties for different devices, this API helps you work with that file.

Comment: and alternative for java? because wurfl is not open source

Comment: It is not open source, no. As far as I remember is it not free for commercial use either. Nevertheless, I think my answer is an answer for your question. For an open source discussion (not only Java), look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673535/best-open-source-wurfl-alternative